How to limit Async uploads to x at a time?
I'm attempting to upload files through a web form to a Google Drive backend using the Resumable Uplaods feature. I'm starting with a script from https://github.com/tanaikech/AsynchronousResumableUploadForGoogleDrive/
I've spent much time on this without success. What I'd like to do is upload 1,000 files. The way that the async script works now is that all 1,000 will upload concurrently. What I'd like to do is upload (for example) 10 files concurrently, then repeat for the next 10, and so on until done. I believe my issue is that I'll need to modify https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js@master/resumableupload_js.min.js (included in index.html). I've already gotten the files split into chunks of 10, but when doing a chunk.forEach..., the async nature of https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js@master/resumableupload_js.min.js still uploads them all in parallel.
What should I be focusing on to change to only limit 10 async responses, and wait until done, then repeat?
To reproduce, use the setup instructions in the README.md from the repo I linked above. Except, use the code below for index.html.
Note the <insert folder ID> in the index.html file below would need to be updated to your own folder ID for this to work.
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="true" />
<input type="button" onclick="run()" value="Upload" />
<div id="progress"></div>

<script>src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js@master/resumableupload_js.min.js"</script>
<script>

function run() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(accessToken => ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(accessToken)).getAuth();
}

function ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(accessToken) {
  const f = document.getElementById("file");
  const chunkSize = 10;
  const totalChunks = Math.ceil(f.files.length / chunkSize);
  console.log("The totalChunks are: " + totalChunks);
  for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
    const startIndex = i * chunkSize;
    console.log("The startIndex is: " + startIndex);
    const endIndex = startIndex + chunkSize;
    console.log("The endIndex is: " + endIndex);
    const chunk = Array.from(f.files).slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    console.log("The chunk is: " + chunk);
    chunk.forEach((file, i) => {
      if (!file) return;
      let fr = new FileReader();
      fr.fileName = file.name;
      fr.fileSize = file.size;
      fr.fileType = file.type;
      fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      fr.onload = e => {
        var id = "p" + ++i;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = id;
        document.getElementById("progress").appendChild(div);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Initializing.";
        const f = e.target;
        const resource = { fileName: fr.fileName, fileSize: fr.fileSize, fileType: fr.fileType, fileBuffer: fr.result, accessToken: accessToken, folderId: "<insert folder ID>" };
        const ru = new ResumableUploadToGoogleDrive();
        ru.Do(resource, function (res, err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          console.log(res);
          let msg = "";
          if (res.status == "Uploading") {
            msg = Math.round((res.progressNumber.current / res.progressNumber.end) * 100) + "% (" + fr.fileName + ")";
          } else {
            msg = res.status + " (" + fr.fileName + ")";
          }

          document.getElementById(id).innerText = msg;
        });
      };
    });
  };
};
</script>


It's great that you are given attribution to the author of the script that you are adapting to your requirements, however, questions onf this site should be self contained. Considering this, please add a [mcve].

Updated with reproducible code example

In your situation, how about the following sample script?
Before you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.
Google Apps Script: code.gs
function getAuth() {
  // DriveApp.createFile(blob) // This is used for adding the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

HTML & Javascript: index.html
Please modify your folder ID to folderId: "root",.
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="true" />
<input type="button" onclick="run()" value="Upload" />
<div id="progress"></div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js@2.0.2/resumableupload_js.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
function run() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(accessToken => ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(accessToken)).getAuth();
}

function upload({ accessToken, file, idx }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.fileName = file.name;
    fr.fileSize = file.size;
    fr.fileType = file.type;
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    fr.onload = e => {
      var id = `p_${idx}`;
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = id;
      document.getElementById("progress").appendChild(div);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Initializing.";
      const f = e.target;
      const resource = {
        fileName: f.fileName,
        fileSize: f.fileSize,
        fileType: f.fileType,
        fileBuffer: f.result,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        folderId: "root",
      };
      const ru = new ResumableUploadToGoogleDrive();
      ru.Do(resource, function (res, err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(res);
        let msg = "";
        if (res.status == "Uploading") {
          msg = Math.round((res.progressNumber.current / res.progressNumber.end) * 100) + `% (${f.fileName})`;
        } else {
          msg = `${res.status} (${f.fileName})`;
        }
        if (res.status == "Done") {
          resolve(res.result);
        }
        document.getElementById(id).innerText = msg;
      });
    };
  });
}


async function ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(accessToken) {

  const n = 10; // You can adjust the chunk size.

  const f = document.getElementById("file");
  const files = [...f.files];
  const splitFiles = [...Array(Math.ceil(files.length / n))].map((_) => files.splice(0, n));
  for (let i = 0; i < splitFiles.length; i++) {
    const res = await Promise.all(splitFiles[i].map(async (file, j) => await upload({ accessToken, file, idx: `${i}_${j}` })));
    console.log(res);
  }
}
</script>

Testing:
When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In this case, const n = 2; is used. So, the files are uploaded every 2 files with the asynchronous process.

References:

ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js (Author: me)
Uploading Multiple Files with Split Asynchronous Processes and Resumable Upload in Google Spreadsheets (Author: me)


Thank you so much, @Tanaike! I've made so much use of your code, and am really appreciative of all you've contributed back. I was hyperfocused on your AsynchronousResumableUploadForGoogleDrive repo and didn't peer too much into ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js for samples. Might I suggest to add those Async samples also to the first repo as well? Nevertheless, this solved it! :)

@Dan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. About Might I suggest to add those Async samples also to the first repo as well?, yes, I added it! https://github.com/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js?tab=readme-ov-file#sample-script-4

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION
This is another method by which you may try to upload 1,000 files, but limit the script to 10 files concurrently at a time.
Here's an example:



After choosing 11 files, the first 10 start downloading, and when they're finished, the 11th file will start to download and complete.

This is the modified version of index.html:
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="true" />
<input type="button" onclick="run()" value="Upload" />
<div id="progress"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js@master/resumableupload_js.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var q = [];
  var c = 10;

  function run() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(accessToken => {
        [...document.getElementById("file").files].forEach(file => {
          q.push({ file, accessToken });
        });
        upload();
      })
      .getAuth();
  }

  function upload() {
    while (q.length > 0 && c > 0) {
      const { file, accessToken } = q.shift();
      ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(file, accessToken);
      c--;
    }
  }

  function ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive(file, accessToken) {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.fileName = file.name;
    fr.fileSize = file.size;
    fr.fileType = file.type;
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    fr.onload = e => {
      const id = "p" + Date.now();
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = id;
      document.getElementById("progress").appendChild(div);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Initializing.";
      const resource = {
        fileName: e.target.fileName,
        fileSize: e.target.fileSize,
        fileType: e.target.fileType,
        fileBuffer: e.target.result,
        accessToken
      };
      const ru = new ResumableUploadToGoogleDrive();
      ru.Do(resource, (res, err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(res);
        let msg = "";
        if (res.status === "Uploading") {
          msg =
            Math.round(
              (res.progressNumber.current / res.progressNumber.end) * 100
            ) +
            "% (" +
            e.target.fileName +
            ")";
        } else {
          msg = res.status + " (" + e.target.fileName + ")";
        }
        if (res.status === "Done") google.script.run.putFileInf(res.result);
        document.getElementById(id).innerText = msg;
        if (res.status === "Done") {
          c++;
          upload();
        }
      });
    };
  }
</script>


The q variable stores the files selected, the c variable serves as the concurrent counter, and the upload() function processes the download 10 at a time.

REFERENCE

Resumable Upload of Multiple Files with Asynchronous Process for Google Drive


This is also a great suggestion!
